# How to trigger kubernetes pod failure with java?

Tags: java, kubernetes, health-monitoring

I tried to to it using this code snipped but it does not work out:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(FAIL)
public Response triggerError(){
    i = i+1;
    if(i==3){
        i=0;
        return Response.serverError().entity("Triggered 500").build();
    }
    return Response.ok().entity("I am fine").build();
}
```

How can I trigger an unhealthy status for a kubernetes pod?

Comment: May I ask why I got the downvote? Of course, this is no specific code question in the sense of "why is 1+1!=1?". But to me it's a pretty clear question. Beside that I couldn't find anything to trigger the recovery policy in kubernetes via code.

Comment: `does not work out` means nothing really. You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/), if a Pod is unhealthy, the container in the pod will be restarted (or not), accordingly to the [restart policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy).

By default, a Pod is considered unhealthy if one of the containers in the Pod exits with the error status.

If the Pod is constantly restarting, its status is shown as `CrashLoopBackOff`.
If a container in a Pod exits with 0 it gets status `Completed` and no more restarts will happen.

You can customize a Pod health check using the [liveliness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) probe syntax:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

Explanation:

> For the first 30 seconds of the Container’s life, there is a /tmp/healthy file. So during the first 30 seconds, the command cat /tmp/healthy returns a success code. After 30 seconds, cat /tmp/healthy returns a failure code.

I hope it would be helpful.